# What does "the magnitude of the coefficients" mean here, and how to compute this quantity based on this table?

Tags: terminology

This is Table 1.1 in [pattern recognition and machine learning (free)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf)

[image]

> We can gain some insight into the problem by examining the values of the coefficients
>   $w^*$ obtained from polynomials of various order, as shown in Table 1.1.
>   We see that, as M increases, the **magnitude** of the coefficients typically gets larger.

what does "the magnitude of the coefficients" mean here, how to compute this quantity based on this table, when M=1 and M=9?

this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167811/comparing-magnitude-of-coefficients-in-a-logistic-regression) seems to be relative, I didn't see a concrete approach (formula) to compute this quantity.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means their general value. For M=0 you get something that is less than one, as M increase the general (absolute) value of the coefficients increase... For M = 9 most coefficients are over 1000, but there are some exception ($w_0$ = 0.35). The use of 'magnitude' here convey that idea that the general value increase with M without specifying an exact metric (average value, difference between min and max... etc.). The important word in the paragraph you cite is 'typically' meaning that this is a rule of thumbs, not an exact rule over an exact metric.

Comment: Are you using "general value" to mean "absolute value"?