# How to test overlapping confidence intervals to see a significant difference between groups in a COX propotional model

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival, p-value, cox-model

Cox proportional models have been done with this result.

[image: Cox result]

The two groups (C, B) had overlapping confidence intervals, while the p-value was significant at p<0.001. I have used this code to get the result :

```
coxph.fit<-coxph(Surv(time_mu , event)~group, data=df)
```

My goal is to find out if there is a significant difference between C and B with a significant p-value. I have found a method in R in this link [Overlapping confidence intervals doesn’t mean non-significant difference](https://randomeffect.net/post/2020/10/09/overlapping-confidence-intervals-doesn-t-mean-non-significant-difference/), but I do not know how to get all CIs. What is the best way to deal with overlappaing CIs in Cox models?

Comment: DO NOT use overlapping CIs to test differences. It's like using a screwdriver to drive a nail -- the wrong tool. There are established statistical methods for testing differences, use those.

Comment: Please let us know

Comment: Not sure what me to let you know. To test a difference, compute a t ratio from an estimate of that difference and its SE. The SE depends on the SEs of the means and their correlation. Because of the need for that correlation, you can't test a difference knowing just the CUs for the means. Plus even if the correlation is zero, overlapping CIs are an incorrect test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no different from any comparison of regression coefficients in a model. See for example [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25520/28500) in the context of logistic regression. It's straightforward here, as `group` isn't involved in interactions with other predictors. Otherwise you would have to specify values for its interacting predictors.

Work in the original regression coefficient log-hazard scale rather than the hazard-ratio scale that you show here. Your null hypothesis is $\beta_B =\beta_C$, where each $\beta$ is the coefficient describing the difference in log-hazard of each group from the reference level of `group`.

You also need the coefficient variance-covariance matrix, which provides the estimates both for the variances of individual coefficients (diagonal terms) and for the covariances between the estimates (off-diagonal terms). Then you apply the formula for the [variance of a sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables) to get the variance of $\beta_B -\beta_C$. The coefficient estimates in the log-hazard scale are taken to be distributed normally, so a z-test provides your test of whether the null hypothesis, $\beta_B -\beta_C=0$, is tenable.

Software typically provides helper functions to do this for you. With R, for example, the `contrast()` function in the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) and the tools in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) can perform such calculations for many types of models and scenarios.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.