# Compare two groups in Cox Proportional Hazards model

Tags: t-test, cox-model, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I have a Cox Proportional Hazards model and I'd like to check if there are statistically significant differences between ECOG groups 1 and 2 (HR: 1.32 vs HR: 2.19). I have thought of doing a paired t-test but I am not sure if that is the right way of doing it. I am not sure if a logRank or a Mantel Haenszel would be appropriate here either.

[image: cox]

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25520/how-to-do-post-hoc-tests-with-logistic-regression/25534#25534 – that question was about logistic regression, but the same rationale applies to Cox PH models.

Comment: Or see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/574816/28500), which is essentially identical to yours and is specifically on a Cox model. You work in the log-hazard coefficient scale and test whether $\beta_{ECOG1}=\beta_{ECOG2}$, using the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates. A t-test isn't appropriate for this type of model, and a simple z-test based on the individual standard errors would erroneously ignore the covariance between the coefficient estimates. Your other suggested approaches wouldn't take the other covariates into account.